# Package gulp-load-plugins not found

Tags: npm, gulp, bower

I am trying to install this plugin which is the Polymer, I do not need the full library, only that plugin, and I am getting the error:
command I type in my terminal is: sudo npm install -g bower 
                                  npm install --save gulp-install

Error I am getting is: bower ENOTFOUND     Package gulp-load-plugins not found

Comment: it would help if you linked the contents of your package.json and all files relevant to gulp. The package in the error is a bootstraper for other gulp plugins.

Answer (score 0):

gulp-load-plugins is a npm module, I am not sure why are you trying to install it using bower.

To install gulp-load-plugins you have to use npm command

if you are searching for particular bower component you can search here http://bower.io/search/